# How do I re-order the data point series in my Excel chart in date order?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have created a chart with a 24-month span of data points.  Despite the fact that the data itself is populated in date order in the table I am creating the chart from, for some reason the chart insists on re-ordering the data points.  I need the chart to display in date order.
Here's an example of what I mean - I have created a table with dates and associated data points such as the below:

Sep 2019 -    5
Oct 2019 -    8
Nov 2019 -    2
Dec 2019 -    4
Jan 2020 -    5
Feb 2020 -   1

However, once I insert a chart on the table, for some reason, the data points get plotted in the following order: Jan 2020, Feb 2020, Sept 2019, Oct 2019, Nov 2019, Dec 2019.

I have read countless articles on this and can't seem to find the answer of how to ensure the series is plotted in the order that the table is created in - any help would be GREATLY appreciated!!!

Comment: show an image of the chart

Answer (score 2):

There are different scenarios with different solutions here.

If the "dates" are text, then they should plot in the order of the data source, regardless of chart type.

If the dates are real dates, then the plot order can be determined by the axis type in some charts (line, column), which support either text axis (plot in order of data source), or date axis (plots chronologically).

I've intentionally jumbled your data source into non-chronological order. The dates are real dates and the plot order is different for the two sample column charts.

[image]

If your data plots in an unusual order,

- check that the dates are really the date values you require. Is it "January 2020"? Or is it "January 20"? As in "20th January". Because the "wrong" sort order you mention suggests that the months are in chronological order from Jan to Dec of the same year.
- Or use a text axis instead of a date axis, so the points are plotted in the order of the data source.

Comment: THANK YOU, THANK YOU, THANK YOU A MILLION TIMES!!  I was able to get the axis to reflect the order I intended by choosing 'Text Axis.'  I cannot thank you enough!!

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.